# Is it true that $\int_a^b \min\{f,g\}(x)\,dx \leq \min\left\{\int_a^b f(x)\,dx, \int_a^b g(x)\,dx \right\}$ for continuous $f,g$ on $[a,b]?$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Question: Given continuous functions $f$ and $g$ on $[a,b],$ is it true that 
>   $$\int_a^b \min\{f,g\}(x)\,dx \leq \min\left\{\int_a^b f(x)\,dx, \int_a^b g(x)\,dx \right\}?$$

Intuitively, it sounds true to me. But I do not now how to prove it.

Comment: $\min(f, g)(x) \le f(x)$, and $\min(f,g)(x) \le g(x)$. So  ...

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2764486/42969 for a proof of the corresponding relation with $\max$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is true.

$min({f , g})(x) \leq f(x)$

$min({f , g})(x) \leq g(x)$

Thus, for $b \geq a$,

$\int_{a}^{b}{min({f,g})(x)}dx \leq \int_{a}^{b}{f(x)}dx$

$\int_{a}^{b}{min({f,g})(x)}dx \leq \int_{a}^{b}{g(x)}dx$

Consequently,

$\int_{a}^{b}{min({f,g})(x)}dx \leq min(\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)}dx , \int_{a}^{b}{g(x)}dx) $

Comment: can we remove the continuity here?

Comment: Yes, continuity is not a requirement here.